# Error when checking target: expected to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to make `image2image` translation and
my dataset is composed of Mnist(256*256) and transformed Mnist(256*256)

I am literally suffering from this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_transpose_57 to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 3)
```

My layer seems like this :

```
_______________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_56 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 17)      476       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_57 (Conv2D)           (None, 256, 256, 32)      4928      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_37 (MaxPooling (None, 128, 128, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_58 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 48)      13872     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_59 (Conv2D)           (None, 128, 128, 64)      27712     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_38 (MaxPooling (None, 64, 64, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_39 (MaxPooling (None, 32, 32, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_60 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 96)        55392     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_61 (Conv2D)           (None, 32, 32, 128)       110720    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPooling (None, 16, 16, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPooling (None, 8, 8, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_62 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 192)         221376    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_63 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 256)         442624    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_64 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_50 (Conv2DT (None, 8, 8, 256)         262400    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_51 (Conv2DT (None, 16, 16, 192)       196800    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_52 (Conv2DT (None, 32, 32, 128)       98432     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_53 (Conv2DT (None, 64, 64, 64)        32832     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_54 (Conv2DT (None, 128, 128, 48)      12336     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_55 (Conv2DT (None, 256, 256, 32)      6176      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_56 (Conv2DT (None, 256, 256, 17)      561       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_57 (Conv2DT (None, 256, 256, 3)       54        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,076,771
Trainable params: 2,076,771
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

idk why this is happening

I changed last layer's output to `(None, 256, 256, 1)`.
And also I changed first layer's input and last layer's output to `(None, 256, 256, 1)`.
but it doesn't work..

```py
import numpy as np
import warnings

import csv
import os
from PIL import Image
import random

from keras.layers import Input
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers import Flatten, Conv2DTranspose
from keras.layers import Conv2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D, pooling
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import ZeroPadding2D
from keras.layers import AveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras.backend as K
from keras.utils import layer_utils, np_utils
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
from keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
from keras.models import Sequential

if __name__ == '__main__':
    training_file_input = 'C:/Users/my/Desktop/input/train/trainig_tfmed'
    training_file_output = 'C:/Users/my/Desktop/input/train/trainig_original'
    test_file_input = 'C:/Users/my/Desktop/input/test/test_tfmed'
    test_file_output = 'C:/Users/my/Desktop/input/test/test_original'
        
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    nop = np.array([None])
    
    training_file_input_list = os.listdir(training_file_input)
    test_file_input_list = os.listdir(test_file_input)
    
    for i in range(1, len(training_file_input_list)+1):
        input_filename = training_file_input + '/tfmed_trainig_' + str(i) + '.jpg'

        input_image = Image.open(input_filename)
        input_image = input_image.convert("RGB")
        input_image = input_image.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        input_image = np.array(input_image, dtype=np.float32)
        x_train.append(input_image)
        #x_train = np.append(nop, input_image)
        
        output_filename = training_file_output + '/original_trainig_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
        output_image = Image.open(output_filename)
        output_image = output_image.convert("RGB")
        output_image = output_image.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        output_image = np.array(output_image, dtype=np.float32)
        y_train.append(output_image)
        #y_train = np.append(nop, input_image)
    ## loading test files
        
    x_test = []
    y_test = []
    
    for i in range(1, len(test_file_input_list)+1):
        input_filename = test_file_input + '/tfmed_test_' + str(i) + '.jpg'

        input_image = Image.open(input_filename)
        input_image = input_image.convert("RGB")
        input_image = input_image.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        input_image = np.array(input_image, dtype=np.float32)
        x_test.append(input_image)
        #x_test = np.append(nop, input_image)
        
        output_filename = test_file_output + '/original_test_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
        output_image = Image.open(output_filename)
        output_image = output_image.convert("RGB")
        output_image = output_image.resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        output_image = np.array(output_image, dtype=np.float32)
        y_test.append(output_image)
        #y_test = np.append(nop, input_image)
#   
    x_train = np.asarray(x_train)
    y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
    x_test = np.asarray(x_test)
    y_test = np.asarray(y_test)

    print('Model load')
    
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(17, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape = (256, 256, 1)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(48, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(96, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(192, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(256, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(192, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(48, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(17, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    print(model.output_shape)
#    model.add(Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
#    print(model.output_shape)
#    model.add(UpSampling2D(1))
#    print(model.output_shape)
#    
    model.summary()
        
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=50)
    
    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print('Loss: ' + str(loss))
    print('Accuracy: ' + str(accuracy))
```

It should work and it needs to be learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MNIST data is grayscale, which means it has a shape of `(h,w,1)` you have set `PIL` to convert the data to `RGB` which has three colour dimensions `(h,w,3)`, the problem is with this line :

```py
input_image = input_image.convert("RGB")
```

Either remove it entirely or replace it with:

```py
input_image = input_image.convert("L")
```

This should give your input data dimension `(256,256,1)`

Comment: input_image = Image.open(input_filename)
        input_image = np.array(input_image, dtype=np.float32)
        input_image = np.reshape(input_image, (256, 256, 1))
        x_test.append(input_image)

i've done by this way! it worked! is it fine?

Comment: are you still getting the value error ? or is the model now running ?

Reshaping should be ok on this dataset, I am not aware of any full color MNIST datasets  so using grayscale or reshaping to  (256, 256, 1) are equivalent.

You can check this directly by loading up  input_image and displaying it as a smoke test

Comment: no it works now! and it seemed okay as i displayed it.

Comment: but actually i got one more problem, i saved my model and predicted. but result is all black(all zeros). do you know why this is occured?